# Error return data null when using "case ... when" in php mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a sample data:

```
users(id, name)  
       1 | peter
       ... 
usermeta(user_id, meta_key, meta_value)
            1   |  level   |    10
            1   |  display |    pc 
           ...   
points(user_id, type, point)
           1  |  like  | 5
           2  | comment| 10     
           ...
```

And mysql:

```
SELECT u.*, 
(case when m.meta_key = 'level' then m.meta_value end) level , 
p.points AS point
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN points p ON p.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN usermeta AS m ON m.user_id = u.id
```

Result level = NULL, how to fix it?

```
id | name | level | point
1  | peter| NULL  |  5
1  | peter| 10    |  10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `m.meta_key = 'level'` as the join condition.

```
SELECT u.*, 
m.meta_value AS level , 
p.points AS point
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN points p ON p.uid = u.id
LEFT JOIN usermeta AS m ON m.user_id = u.id AND m.meta_key = 'level'
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried providing an ELSE clause to your [`CASE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case)? And according to your tables `p.uid` doesn't exist, it should be `p.user_id`, right?

Also, you should use [`INNER JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) in this case as you want to retrieve *only* those cases in which the `id` field in the `users` table matches the ones in `points` and `usermeta` respectively. This should work properly:

```
SELECT
    u.*, 
    CASE WHEN m.meta_key = 'level' THEN m.meta_value ELSE NULL END AS level, 
    p.points AS point
FROM users u
INNER JOIN points p ON p.user_id = u.id
INNER JOIN usermeta m ON m.user_id = u.id
```